# Is there a way to query with a date column with a date range recursively?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I got rows like below with a date column and user name

```
visit_date | user_name
2021-01-01, a
2021-01-02, a
2021-01-03, a
2021-01-04, a
2021-01-04, a
2021-01-01, b
```

and I want a query result like this to get from date and to date with a specific time period.

```
visit_date_from | visit_date_to | user_name | count
2021-01-01, 2021-01-01, a, 1
2021-01-01, 2021-01-02, a, 2
2021-01-02, 2021-01-02, a, 1
2021-01-01, 2021-01-03, a, 3
2021-01-02, 2021-01-03, a, 2
2021-01-03, 2021-01-03, a, 1
2021-01-01, 2021-01-04, a, 5
2021-01-02, 2021-01-04, a, 4
2021-01-03, 2021-01-04, a, 3
2021-01-04, 2021-01-04, a, 2
2021-01-01, 2021-01-05, a, 4
.
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to query like this?

Comment: Do you want this for a specific user? A specific range of dates?

Comment: @ysth I want this for specific range of dates like declaring from_date = '2021-01-01' and to_date = '2021-01-05'

Answer (score 0):

Basic usage of recursive query

```sql
create table t0812 as 
select date_format('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') dat, 'a' nam union all
select date_format('2021-01-02', '%Y-%m-%d') dat, 'a' nam union all
select date_format('2021-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d') dat, 'a' nam union all
select date_format('2021-01-04', '%Y-%m-%d') dat, 'a' nam union all
select date_format('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') dat, 'b' nam
;

with recursive rec(dat, to_dat, nam) as (
select dat, dat, nam from t0812 t0 
union all
select t1.dat,t2.dat, t1.nam 
  from rec t1, 
       t0812 t2 
 where t1.nam = t2.nam 
   and date_add(t1.to_dat, interval 1 day) = t2.dat
)
select * from rec t1
 order by t1.nam, t1.to_dat, t1.dat
;
```